# Как сделать иконки в Navigation Drawer цветными?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Не понимаю почему, но иконки отображаются серыми, хотя сами они все цветные.

[image: Иконки отображаются серыми]

Вот код Activity_main.xml, может быть пригодится.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: как по мне - руками в NavigationDrawer вставить ListView с иконками, какими вы хотите

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Попробуйте оттенок убрать

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо больше.