# Иконки для Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, icon

Сделал Navigation Drawer. Хочу заменить иконки, однако при замене вместо моих иконок имею серые квадраты. Какого формата должны быть эти иконки? или как то по другому их необходимо делать?

Comment: Вроде, где-то в Android studio была утилита для создания иконок сразу для всех разрешений

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535242/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-navigation-drawer-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8?rq=1)

Comment: @TimurVI спасибо помогло